# Grep --line-buffered, can I search the same buffer with the results of the first grep?

Tags: linux, grep, logs

I'm searching a log file in the following format

```
<date> <connection from: ip> <new connection ID> <info> 
<date> <connection ID> <info>
```

I'm using the following to get my IP but then searching for my connection ID takes a few minutes in this log file.

```
tail -f logfile | grep ip --line-buffered
```

Is it possible to first grep for the IP then continue searching based off the connection ID?

The connection ID is not predictable and the following lines in the log after my match are not necessarily my connection ID tied to my IP.

Comment: Probably not with grep, but you may be able to do this with awk.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `awk` e.g.  `awk -F '>|<' '/ip/{c=$6};c && $4==c'` (where `ip` is the actual IP and `$4` is the ID)

Answer (score 1):

No.

When you do

```
tail -f logfile | grep "ip-address" --line-buffered
```

you will *only* get the lines matching the `ip-address` pattern. Further `grep` invocations to the pipeline after this would not be able to see any other lines from the original logfile.

Without seeing a few examples of how the logfile may look, it would be really difficult to (blindly) find a working solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use several patterns in your grep command, for example to grep both lines with 'ip' and 'connection ID':

```
tail -f logfile | grep -E 'ip|connection ID' --line-buffered
```

Comment: The issue is that the connection ID is not predictable, according to the OP.

Comment: so, maybe is there a pattern to match the connectionID that could be implemented as a regular expression in grep, or maybe awk ?

Comment: Yes, maybe, but we don't know.

Comment: If the connection ID is a single word, it could be easily caught in awk instead of grep. Maybe could you post a sample of lines you need to match.